# bad format of an array using latex

Tags: tables

I'm tryning to draw an array with latex, unfortunatly i'm getting a bad print.

Here is what i'm getting:

[image]

Here is the part i'm adding to show the array:

```
   \begin{tabular}{|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|}
  \hline
  N & 1 & 2 &3& 4 &5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17 \\
  \hline
  Solution & 1& 1& 1& 2& 3& 3& 4& 5& 5& 5& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 9& 9 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to obtain with these unknown specifiers (`a, b, c, d, e, &c.`)?

Comment: The unknown specifiers `a b d e f g h i j k m n o q` are transformed into `c` (with error messages); `l`, `c` and `r` are legal; also `p` is legal, but it requires `{<length>}` after it, so TeX throws two further errors and inserts `0pt` for the missing length.

Comment: @Bernard i thought just i must put those alphabets to draw the array,i trie to delete them but i get some errors.

Comment: @zakzak You want a caged table with 18 centered columns: `\begin{tabular}{|*{18}{c|}}` is the correct input.

Comment: @egreg can you put it as a response.it worked well for me.thank you for the helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `\begin{tabular}` should contain a specification for the columns you want. The standard legal specifiers are

- `c` for a centered column;
- `l` for a left aligned column;
- `r` for a right aligned column;
- `|` for a vertical line between columns (or at either side of the table);
- `p` for a “paragraph” column, but it should be be followed by a width specification such as `p{2cm}` (any length specification is valid);
- `@` for intercolumn material different from the standard spacing, with the material in braces after `@`, for instance `@{}` will remove the intercolumn spacing, `@{+}` would insert a `+` instead of the space.

One can use the shorthand

```
*{<number>}{<specifiers>}
```

for repeating a group of column specifiers the given number of times. In your case you want eighteen groups of the form `c|` preceded by a single `|`, so

```
\begin{tabular}{ | *{18}{c|} }
```

which is easier to read than the equivalent

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
```

With your code you get a large number of errors of the form

```
! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 ...lar}{|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|}
```

These are raised because of `a b d e f g h i j k m n o q` that are illegal (and LaTeX tries to recover with `c` instead). There is also

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   |
l.7 ...&3& 4 &5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 1
                                                  5& 16& 17 \\
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   |
l.7 ...&3& 4 &5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 1
                                                  5& 16& 17 \\
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)
```

which is due to `p` being followed by `|` instead of a length in braces.

There is some output thanks to the error recovery, but it's just what it is. *Never* disregard errors during typesetting.